# PDO not returning results from SELECT on more than 1 column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The server is running PHP 5.2.8. PDO has mysql 5.1.30 drivers installed.

Alright, so I am trying to figure out some PDO ( and this is just killing me. When I run the code below, I get the expected results, no problem.

However, whenever I try to add more than one column (or *) to the SELECT, there is no reply from the query - no results whatsoever. I have tried everything - I know it must be something simple. Any suggestions as to why more than one column fails to return any rows?

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbname = "dbname";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo 'Connected to database<br />';

    /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
    $sql = "SELECT LastName FROM staff";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo $row['LastName'] . '<br />';
    }

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Again, if I try to add columns in the statement stored in $sql to anything other than a single column, I get bupkis. For example:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM staff
```

returns zero results. Both columns exist - if requested separately, they return expected results. When combined, the query takes quite some time, then returns nothing.

No exception is caught by the catch block.

Comment: Please switch PDO error reporting from silent to exception. That will probably help.

Comment: Do you get an error? Or the query just returns empty?

Comment: @nikic - no errors with Exception, sorry this was some changed code I threw in there to see if changing the parsing of the results array would help. I had Exception on previously.

Comment: Show how you try to add more than one column. The code is ok, if you have those columns in your table, then it should display all results.

Comment: @meze I'm simply having the query read "SELECT FirstName, LastName from staff". Both columns exist - if requested separately, they return expected results. When combined, the query/request of the server takes quite some time, then returns nothing.

Comment: @gradatc: you mean `foreach ($dbh->query("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM staff") as $row) { echo $row['FirstName'] . '<br />' . $row['LastName'];}` doesn't work?

Comment: Does it show an exception after you turned them on?

Comment: @meze: You got it. I actually had been just changing the $sql variable, but I just hardcoded in your code just now, to no avail. I'm telling you - it is really driving me nuts. 'Cause `code`foreach ($dbh->query("SELECT LastName FROM staff") as $row) { echo $row['LastName'] . '<br />';}`code` works.

Comment: @aaz = I actually just tested for FALSE. Nothing happens. When I say I get nothing back - it is as if the entire section of code fails somehow - i get just a plain white screen. I don't even get 'echo' code that I placed in the code prior to this PDO stuff

Comment: Any chance a custom error handler is in effect? Try `restore_error_handler()` and `restore_exception_handler()` at the start of the block.

Comment: @aaz: no changes. I've removed all the rest of the code and am just running what you see above to make sure nothing else screwy was going on. I added the restores(), but no new data. Just about a 6.3 second delay and then a white screen with no input from ANY of the code. If I intentionally screw up the SQL or the PDO calls, I get exceptions, no problem.

Comment: It kind of sounds like the Apache process is crashing. Maybe out of memory? Could you try a `LIMIT 1` on your query? Could you try `SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(FirstName), CHAR_LENGTH(LastName)`?

Comment: that's interesting. try to upgrade php or reinstall? Also check  that `display_errors` is enabled in your php.ini

Comment: I can't really reinstall or upgrade PHP, no access to that stuff. Though I can ask. I did re-write with mysqli and it works just fine... thought I am really not feeling using mysqli, but I will have to, I guess. Thank you all for your help!!!

Comment: Why not try  `$query = $dbh->prepare($sql); $query->execute(); while($row=$query->fetch()) { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a number of issues here, mostly in your code that handles reading the values returned by the query.  I have taken the liberty of changing a few things and rewriting this to use prepare statements, which is a function that PDO provides that you should take advantage of.

On prepare statements:
Why use them: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html
PHP PDO doc:  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Here is the core code:

```
try {
  //open database
  $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);  

  $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

  //define sql query
  $sql = "SELECT LastName FROM staff";

  //prepare the query for execution 
  $qresult = $dbh->prepare($sql);

  //insert code below to handle parameters to the sql query here

  //execute the query
  $qresult->execute();

  //fetch the results
  foreach ($qresult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
    {
    echo $row['LastName'] . '<br />';
    }


} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$qresult = null;  //close the result set
$dbh = null;  //close the database
```

Note, that I have replaced the call to query() with a couple of lines that call prepare() then execute().  You can then easily insert the following lines in between the prepare() and execute() calls to handle passing parameterized queries.  This will help reduce chances of sql injection.

I have also changed the way you are accessing the retirned valued by specifying that I want them returned as and associative array, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC. This will get you a result set that you can iterate through like you would have using the old mysql interfaces.

If your query was a parameterized query like:

```
$sql="SELECT LastName FROM staff WHERE LastName=':lastname'";
```

where :lastname is the parameter.

Here is the code you would insert at the comment to handle this, (this code will handle multiple parameters.  Simply add additional elements to the $param array):

```
//bind parameters to the prepared statement
$param = array(':lastname'=>'Jones');
foreach ($param as $key => $value) {
  $qresult->bindValue($key,$value);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on the parameterized query. I hadn't used one because it was a SELECT call w/o any variable inputs. I tried your code, which returns the letter "W" - and that's it. It, too, fails with anything more than a single column request in the SELECT statement. Again, the old mysqli works w/o a problem... weird. But thanks again for the input. If I ever get this sorted out, I'll be sure to switch to code more this style.

Comment: $sql= "SELECT s.LastName, s.FirstName FROM staff s"  shoudl return both.  Remember, you have to add another $row['rownname'] in the loop as well.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you separate the columns in the SELECT with a comma (space on either side of the comma is okay, but not required). If you want to select all columns, have only a * with no other characters.